# Get 'libs' directory from within Python regardless of Python installation structure

Tags: python, path, travis-ci

While patching a program I wrote I noticed that I had no safe way to actually get the directory of 'libs', or even 'include' from within the Python installation itself. Every single time I tried to find any python used directory, I just assumed they would always be in the same place, and thus hard-coded them in. Now you might wonder why I am having trouble with this, I mean it's just a simple `join` call after a `sys` check, right?

```
import os, sys

python_base_directory = sys.exec_prefix
libs_directory = os.path.join(python_base_directory, 'libs')
```

This code works most of the time, but will fail when you are using a virtual environment, or in my case, using travis_ci.

I want to be able to get the path to the 'libs' directory ***without hard coding anything***.

Comment: This looks like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please make sure to ask about your problem, not what you think the solution might be. What is your _real_ goal?

Comment: To get the 'libs' directory path no matter python installation structure

Comment: For _what purpose_? There is probably a better way to approach your problem.

Comment: To find if libpythonXY.a exists within that folder

Comment: That is almost certainly not your real goal. What do you intend to do with that information once you have it? Please review the XY Problem link I included in my first comment.

Comment: I see what you mean. Ill ask another question, and edit this one with a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341553/return-the-include-and-libs-directories-from-within-python