# Return the include and runtime lib directories from within Python

Tags: python, gcc, static-libraries, python-c-extension

Lets say I want to use `gcc` from the command line in order to compile a C extension of Python. I'd structure the call something like this:

```
gcc -o applesauce.pyd -I C:/Python35/include -L C:/Python35/libs -l python35 applesauce.c
```

I noticed that the `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` options are absolutely necessary, or else you will get an error that looks something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985109/how-to-compile-c-code-from-cython-with-gcc). These commands tell gcc where to look for the headers (`-I`), where to look for the static libraries (`-L`), and which static library to actually use (`python35`, which actually translates to `libpython35.a`).

Now, this is obviously really easy to get the `libs` and `include` directories if its your machine, as they never change if you don't want them to. However, I was writing a program that calls `gcc` from the command line, that *other people will be using*. The line where this call occurs looks something like this:

```
from subprocess import call
import sys
filename = applesauce.c
include_directory = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'include')
libs_directory = os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'libs')

call(['gcc', ..., '-I', include_direcory, '-L', libs_directory, ...])
```

#### However, others will have different platforms and different Python installation structures, so just joining the paths won't always work.

Instead, I need a solution *from within Python* that will reliably return the `include` and `libs` directories.

### Edit:

I looked at the module `distutils.ccompiler`, and found many useful functions that would in part use distutils, but make it customizable for me to make my compiler entirely cross platform. The only thing is, I need to pass it the include and runtime libraries...

### Edit 2:

I looked at `distutils.sysconfig` an I am able to reliably return the 'include' directory including all the header files. I still have no idea how to get the runtime library.

The `distutils.ccompiler` docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler)

The program that needs this functionality is named [Cyther](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cyther)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of [`build_ext.py`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py) from `distutils` in the method `finalize_options` you will find code for different platforms used to locate libs.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to compile extensions is to use `distutils`, [like this](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html);

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
setup(name='foobar',
      version='1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['foo.c'])],
      )
```

Keep in mind that compared to unix/linux, [compiling extensions on ms-windows is not straightforward](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/) because different versions of the ms compiler are tightly coupled with the corresponding C library. So on ms-windows you have to compile extensions for Python x.y with the same compiler that Python x.y was compiled with. This means using old and unsupported tools for e.g. Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4. The situation is changing ([part 1](http://stevedower.id.au/blog/building-for-python-3-5/), [part 2](http://stevedower.id.au/blog/building-for-python-3-5-part-two/)) with Python 3.5.

**Edit:**
Having looked in the problem more, I doubt that what you want is 100% achievable. Given that the tools needed for compiling and linking are by definition outside of Python and that they are not even necessarily the tools that Python was compiled with, the information in `sys` and `sysconfig` is not guaranteed to an accurate representation of the system that Python is actually installed on. E.g. most ms-windows machines will not have developer tools installed. And even on POSIX platforms there can be a difference between the installed C compiler and the compiler that built Python especially when it is installed as a binary package.

Comment: I used to do this for years, and due to bugs and a variety of painful incompatabilities with distutils and vcvarsall.bat, I wrote Cyther (https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=Cyther&version=0.4.2). My question is one of the current bugs in Cyther. I know this is one way you can do it. I'm just not asking about that way, sorry.

Comment: Which platform causes most problems? Windows, POSIX or OS-X?

Comment: Using distutils to compile, windows gives me the hardest time. Using Cyther, linux gives me the hardest time

Comment: How would `distutils` even supposedly do it if it were 'not possible'

Comment: Well, if `distutils` were perfect we wouldn't be having this conversation... And I'm not saying it is impossible, just not 100% *reliable*.